# onclick Tag not working with custom sorting function enabled

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net-core, razor

I have a gallery with images, these images can be dragged to another place and also dragged back. When dragging them back, a sort function places them at the correct place again (order of ID).

now since I made this function, my onClick Tag function for the Image tag doesn't work anymore
can someone explain me why this is and how I can solve this?

**HTML (Razor):**

```
<ul class="gallery col-md-8 borderBoxes" id="gallery">
        @for (int i = 0; i < Model.PageList.Count; i++)
        {
            <li class="imageListItem ui-icon-zoomin" id="@Model.PageList[i].ID">
                <figure id="@(i+1)">
                    <img class="pages small" src="data:image/jpeg;base64,@Model.PageList[i].ImageBaase64" onclick="imageLarger(this)" />
                </figure>
            </li>

        }
    </ul>
```

**OnClickFunction (JS):**

```
function imageLarger(image) {
    if ($(image).width() === 700) {
        $(image).width(100);
        setTimeout(function () {
            $(image).removeClass("largePages");
            $("li", $("#gallery")).draggable("option", "disabled", false);
        }, 300);

    } else {
        $("li", $("#gallery")).draggable("option", "disabled", true);
        $(image).width(700);
        $(image).addClass("largePages");
    }
};
```

**SortFunction (JS):**

```
 function sortByImageID() {
    var gallery = document.getElementById("gallery");
    var galleryItems = gallery.getElementsByClassName("imageListItem");
    for (var i = 0; i < galleryItems.length; i++) {

        var listitems = [];
        for (i = 0; i < galleryItems.length; i++) {
            listitems.push(galleryItems.item(i));
        }
        listitems.sort(function (a, b) {
            var compA = a.getElementsByTagName("figure")[0].getAttribute('id');
            var compB = b.getElementsByTagName("figure")[0].getAttribute('id');
            return (parseInt(compA) < parseInt(compB)) ? -1 : (parseInt(compA) > parseInt(compB)) ? 1 : 0;
        });
        for (i = 0; i < listitems.length; i++) {
            gallery.appendChild(listitems[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: check the order of functions calls. sortByImageID should run after your drag/drop finished e.g. on mouseup event

Comment: When you use the SortFunction,and what does `I have a gallery with images, these images can be dragged to another place and also dragged back. When dragging them back, a sort function places them at the correct place again (order of ID).`mean?

Comment: @YiyiYou I have two divs, where the User can drag and drop these Images from and to. The images are rendered pages from a pdf. To maintain the order of the pdf (initial loading order resembled by the ID of the img) i use the sorting function. so page 3 is before page 5 even if page 4 is not dragged to the other place.
and i basicaly try to use the sorting function everytime a change happens to any of the pages in any of the divs.

Comment: @IvanSatsiuk I guess you where right, i called the sort function at a place after the "onClick" should be fired, but because of the click, an accept handler from JQueryUI droppable prevented the function from working properly. I really need to refactor my code. Thank you